# Samsung Galaxy: Running Android app disappears from background stack list

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, galaxy, back-stack

On my Samsung galaxy tablet, when the app goes to background (by pressing the home screen), it completely disappears from the back stack (where you can see all the open apps). Yet when I open the app with the icon manually again the state is clearly restored.

Is this a manifest settings or similar? I cant figure it out

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in your manifest launcher activity. Try set it to `false`:`android:excludeFromRecents="false"`